# Nested gridview get outer gridview row index on inner gridview footer button click

Tags: c#

I have a nested gridview with a add button in the footer of one column and a textbox in the footer of another column.  When I click the add button, it would add a row into the nested gridview with the value that was entered in the textbox.  I am trying to figure out how to get the row index of the outer gridview in the add button click function.

Or is there a better way to accomplish what I have described above in general?

Comment: Is this WPF or Winforms?

Comment: Not sure if its related to either of those, but it is being developed for a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onclick event do:

```
                                    //Button Row    //GridView      //Parent row
var parentRow = (GridViewRow)sender.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer;
var index = parentRow.RowIndex;
```